# Angular 6: Trying to make synchronous call (delete) on browser close event (beforeunload/unload event of browser)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, synchronous, browser-close

Actually, I want to update a flag in Db using a service call(Delete method) once the user close the browser. I am able to detect browser close action using `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` events but async call doesn't work for me(sometimes in debugging mode it works fine but on higher env it doesn't work).

Then, I tried to make sync request but then I found that Chrome now disallows synchronous XHR during page dismissal when the page is being navigated away from or closed by the user. 
check link : https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4664843055398912

I have tried new `XMLHttpRequest()` as sync, fetch api also `Navigator.sendBeacon()` but unfortunately nothing works for me.

Please suggest something which works because I have visited so many posts but nothing works for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some solution for this. Hope so any one of them solves your issue.

```
constructor() {
    window.onbeforeunload = ()=>{
      //call API here
    }
  }
```

In your component constructor write above code

OR

In my opinion the better idea is making the heartbeat api that sends requests every N seconds to notify server that the session is active and the user is online. On the server check every M minutes if there was no heartbeat requests for more than N seconds: if it is so - execute the API request(what you wanted to execute on crash).

OR

> 'beforeunload' would be trigger when refreshing pages, closing tab, or closing the browser.

```
  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
    beforeUnload(e: Event) {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
```

OR

It is not possible to ensure that every time an user exits a browser page a specific function will be triggered. The reason is that the browser could close the window for many reasons. Yes it could be a user action but this is not the only case. For example The browser could crash.

In my case I will have to find another strategy to track the time the user stays on the page. For example I am planning to send a lot of API calls before the user exits with all the informations I need to understand his stay on the page. I will update the answer when I will reach a good solution. Anyway I will still wait for better answers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, I am clear about the scenario in which I need to execute this service call but my issue is with the how I can make this call successfully so that it will call the api in sync way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fetch API.
The syntax would be:

```js
fetch('API', {
    method: 'POST', // Other opn are also supported like GET,PUT DELETE
    body: '',
    keepalive: true
});
```

Just an additional read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API